# Calculating area with Integrals, but with exponential?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

[image: Find the Area of the Shaded Region]

So, I'm stuck here because I'm not sure quite what the bounds are -- from $(1,e)$:

$$\int_{e}^{1}\ xe^{x^2}-e^x\,dx$$

Comment: The $x$-range is from what $x$-value to what $x$-value?

Comment: Your sign in the integral is wrong because $e^x > x e^{x^2}$ in the range $0 < x < 1$ and your limits are wrong because the range is $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\exp(x)$ is bigger than $1$.

Also, $x$ goes from $0$ to $1$.

Hence the right integral should be

$$\int_0^1 \exp(x) - x \exp(x^2) \, dx$$

Comment: Thanks Siong, appreciate the clarity!

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\limits_{x=0}^1 \left( e^x - x e^{x^2}\right) dx = \left\{-\frac{e-1}{2 \log (e)}+e-1\right\}$$